# Image Corruption while Averaging Image

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote following code to calculate average of images.

```
cv::Mat image(image_list[0].rows, image_list[0].cols, CV_64FC1);

for (unsigned int list_index = 0; list_index < image_list.size(); ++list_index) {
    int image_row = image_list[list_index].rows;
    int image_col = image_list[list_index].cols;

    for (int row = 0; row < image_row; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < image_col; ++col) {
            image.at<double>(row, col) += static_cast<double>(image_list[list_index].at<uchar>(row, col));
        }
    }
}

for (int row = 0; row < image.rows; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < image.cols; ++col) {
        image.at<double>(row, col) = cvRound(image.at<double>(row, col) / image_list.size());
    }
}

image.convertTo(image, CV_8UC1);
resultant_average_image = image;
```

Here image is initialized with first element of image_list vector and after doing calculations the result is saved to resultant_average_image (which is an attribute of class).
The problem is while I am doing that, even usually it shows me expected result. Sometimes it shows me a corrupted image as a result. I couldn't find the reason of this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the original images, which lead to unexpected results? Maybe there are some pixel values, which overflow (not in range 0-255), leading to unexpected results, but it is hard to comment without original images at hand.

Comment: Problem is solved but thank you. There weren't a constant error. I mean images were arbitrary selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the first line,

```
cv::Mat image(image_list[0].rows, image_list[0].cols, CV_64FC1);
```

allocates an image with *memory that has not been initialized*. Often, it may be zero but not always. That could explain why the result image looks corrupted. Try to add the line

```
image = cv::Scalar(0.0);
```

just after you allocated the image.

Also, I would take care of the special case that `image_list` could be empty.

Comment: I work on Qt now so if size of image_list is 0 or 1, user is warned about situation. In addition to that I tried your your solution and it seems to work. I thought it would already be initialized. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I have probably done the same mistake myself. But it seems like the philosophy in C++ generally is to default to things that don't cost anything. So leaving the memory uninitialized is a sensible default according to this philosophy.